# i m not able to display textbox for telephone number in HTML

Tags: html

```
<label for="telno" class="control-label col-sm-3">
    <font color="#FF0000">*</font><strong>Telephone number</strong>
</label>
<div class="col-sm-3"
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telno" id="telno" maxlength="10"/>
</div>
```

i m not able to display textbox for telephone number 
why it is not displaying textbox using html

Comment: <input type="number">

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the div tag . please use as below

```html
<label for="telno" class="control-label col-sm-3"><font color="#FF0000">*</font><strong>Telephone number</strong></label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telno" id="telno" maxlength="10"/>

                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this 
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varunaaruru/pjyvtms7/1/)

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
         <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telno" id="telno" maxlength="10"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close of div tag not proper, here is the error `<div class="col-sm-3"`

do this `<div class="col-sm-3">`